# Calculate overall accuracy with FAR and FRR

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science

I made a system that detects and counts traffic violations specifically vehicular obstructions in the pedestrian crossing lane. My inputs are videos. To test the program, I'd compare the violation count from my manual observation of the video (ground truth) against the violation count from my program.

Example:

## Video 1

---

Ground Truth: 10 violations

Program Count:  8 violations (False accept: 2, False Reject: 4)

**FAR**: 2/8 = 25%

**FRR**: 4/8 = 50%

**Overall accuracy**: (8 violations - 2 false accepts) / 10 total violations = 60%

Are my computations correct especially the overall accuracy? Also what is the formula  for the equal error rate (EER)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAR and FRR should be computed relatively to the number of observations, not the expected number of positive observations.

**EDIT**

As an example, imagine there have been 100 observations and your program splitted them in 8 violations (including 2 false accept) and 92 non violations (including 4 false reject) when it should have been 10 violations and 90 non violations, then :

**FAR** = 2/100 = 2%

**FRR** = 4/100 = 4%

I think accuracy is correct as the program has indeed detected 60% of the violations.

Comment: Ohh okay so it should be 2/8 and 4/8 for the FAR and FRR respectively? How about my computation for the overall accuracy?

Comment: Not 8 but the total number of observations, that is the number of times the program had to decide whether there have been a violation. i'll edit my answer to add an example